# ros-hydro-rosserial-arduino DUE

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

is there anybody using the new Arduino DUE with rosserial arduino ?
Currently I'm not able to compile anything for the new CPU type, because of missing header files...

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81366/ros-hydro-rosserial-arduino-due/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume by your question title that you are using debs -- I would suggest instead doing a source install from https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial and noting these two issues pull requests:

- https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/64 (already merged into hydro-devel, should make it easy to use DUE)
- https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/58 (not merged, not going to be merged, but notes some issues with the default examples due to problems with the DUE)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1